# Error in firefox with dates

Tags: jquery

Can anybody help me why this script fails in firefox, but works in all other browsers?

I have a function then is the date before today, then run something.
Return values:

```
selDate : Mon Dec 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
today: Tue Dec 02 2014 09:15:06 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Works fine in all browsers, but not in firefox.

```
var dayid = $(this).attr('id');
var selDate = new Date(dayid + "Dec 2014");
var today = new Date();

if ((selDate < today) || (selDate == today)) {
//YES the selDate is before today.
}else{
//NO
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is there is no space between the date part and month

```
var selDate = new Date(dayid + " Dec 2014");
```

Also there is a problem with the value for today, as it will have time part also. So

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0)
```